# JavaScript - simple program using (conditions, random, boolean)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have built a small program as a challenge as I am learning JavaScript. The program is build on the function of Math.random, also it uses conditional statements and boolean assignments.

My question is: in the code below i was told that you dont have to strictly equalise the boolean correctGuess to true what is the reason for this, meaning 
should i do `if (correctGuess === true)` followed by an else statement or `if (correctGuess)` then followed by an else statement.

here is the code:

```
var correctGuess = false;
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
var guess = prompt("I am thinking of a number between 1 and 6. What is it?");
if (parseInt(guess) === randomNumber ) {
    correctGuess = true;
} else if (parseInt(guess) < randomNumber) {
    var guessMore = prompt(" Sorry, your guess whas too low. Try again");
    if ( parseInt(guessMore) === randomNumber) {
        correctGuess = true;
    }
} else if (parseInt(guess) > randomNumber) {
    var guessLess = prompt("sorry, your guess was too high. Try again");
    if (parseInt(guessLess) === randomNumber) {
        correctGuess = true;
    }
}
if ( correctGuess ) {
    document.write("<p>You guessed the number!<p>");
} else {
    document.write("<p>Sorry. The number was " + randomNumber + ".<p>");
}
```

Comment: Either is completely valid, the decision whether to use is down to your personal preference for clarity. Personally I'd use the latter and cut down on extra typing.

Comment: phuzi if you post it as an answer ill accept your answer, you made it easier to understand. i think for now ill go with using the strict equal operator since i just began learning it makes the code easier for me to read and understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you need to check `correctGuess` variable to `boolean` -> `if (correctGuess === true)` is right choise.

without `===` in `if ( correctGuess )` call you will have `true` with: `correctGuess = {}`, `correctGuess = []`, `correctGuess = "string"`, `correctGuess = 1` etc.

But if you sure, that `correctGuess` variable is always `boolean` (like in your code) - you can use `if (correctGuess)` call - and it will work perfectly.

You can read more about type conversion here - http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Comment: thanks this was by far the easiest to understand for me

Comment: would you say it would be a safer option to go with "if (correct guess === true)" ?

Comment: Yes it is. Stricly equality comparision is safer. Also it can be unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, it's safer. I'm agree with @frikinside

Comment: You're a bit wrong regarding correctGuess = {} or correctGuess = []:
If you write if({} == true) alert("true") the alert will not fire.
However if you write if({}) alert("true") it will fire.
Look at this example: https://jsfiddle.net/o5kjLzv3/

Comment: `if({} == true)` will not return true, but `if({})` - will

Answer (score 1):

if i correctly understand question. You don't know difference between `if(true === true)` and `if(true)`. this is boolean operand. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra